# Restructing nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to match node attribute value and if the same value appear in another node attribute i have to merge both of them. so for example i have an xml

```
<xml>
   <title>
   <metadata>
    <ref cite="ABC" relevance="2"/>
    </metadata>
     <body>
       <para>
            <text>(some text from title)</text>
      </para>
     </body>
    </title>
    <title>
      <metadata>
         <ref cite="ABC" relevance="1"/>
      </metadata>
     <body>
       <para>
            <text>(some more text from title 2)</text>
      </para>
     </body>
    </title>

    <mainbody>
        <targetref cite="ABC"/>
        <text>This is a text</text>  
   </mainbody>
 </xml>
```

so after a transformtion the output should be like below, so based on cite "ABC" of element title/metadata/ref and sort by relevance (1,2....) the content of title get merged into the text element of mainbody if cite of element "targetref" matches cite of element "ref"

```
<xml>
  <mainbody>
    <targetref cite="ABC"/>
    <text>This is a text 
        <para><text>(some more text from title 2)</text></para>
       <para><text>(some text from title)</text></para> 
    </text>
   </mainbody>
 </xml>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here some xslt that does what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="mainbody">
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="targetref"/>
        <xsl:element name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="key" select="targetref/@cite"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/xml/title[metadata/ref/@cite=$key]">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="metadata/ref/@relevance" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="body/para"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml/title"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

trick is to ignore nodes xml/title on the normal flow, we focus on mainbody tag, after that we call a for-each to select and order the required nodes and write the information inside the mainbody where we want it. the selection need a variable ($key) to filter as apecified on mainbody

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by means of a key to look up the **title** records based on the metadate ref value:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="title" use="metadata/ref/@cite" />
```

Then, assuming you are positioned on the **text** element within the mainbody, you can look them up like so, and sorting them at the same time

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', preceding-sibling::targetref/@cite)/body/para">
   <xsl:sort select="../../metadata/ref/@relevance" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="ref" match="title" use="metadata/ref/@cite" />
   <xsl:template match="title" />

  <xsl:template match="mainbody/text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', preceding-sibling::targetref/@cite)/body/para" >
         <xsl:sort select="../../metadata/ref/@relevance" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<xml>
    <mainbody>
        <targetref cite="ABC"/>
        <text>This is a text
            <para>
                <text>(some more text from title 2)</text>
            </para>
            <para>
                <text>(some text from title)</text>
            </para></text>
    </mainbody>
</xml>
```